# What is wrong with this inductive proof?

Tags: proof-verification, induction

I have found a startling proof by induction which is clearly wrong.

Let L(n) represent Lucas numbers. L(0)=2, L(1)=1 
L(n) = L(n-1) + L(n-2)

Let F(n) denote a Fibonacci number. F(0) = 0, F(1) = 1, 
F(n) = F(n-1) + F(n-2)

We set out to prove the premise that L(n) = F(n+3), for all n greater than 0

Base Step : An easy substitution of n = 0 verifies this.

Hypothesis step : For all j in between 0 and K, we assume that 
L(k) = F(k+3)

Induction step : We need to prove that L(k+1) = F(k+4)

Since we have used the principles of strong induction, we know that P(k-1) is also true.

Therefore, L(k-1) = F(k+2)
We add this step and out induction hypothesis.

LHS : L(k-1) + L(k) = L(k+1)
RHS : F(K + 2) + F(k +3) = F(K + 4)

Our induction step is proved. QED?

This result is clearly false. Can someone explain why? I have been told that strong and weak induction are equivalent.

Comment: The recursive formulas need the previous two terms. So you inductive base steps would require verification for two consecutive values, not just one. Otherwise, your third paragraph to the last would fail.

Comment: What happens in the inductive hypothesis when $k=0$?  (Do you have all the assumptions that you need?)

Comment: Hmm... Yeah, two base cases need to be verified.

Answer (score 1):

In your inductive step, you use both $P(k)$ and $P(k-1)$. However, in your base step, you only check for one value.

In other words, your inductive step is true for $n \geq 2$, so you need to include $n=1$ in your base step.